# Multiple recipients PHP contact form

Tags: php

Ive made a contact form and I need it to go to mulitple recipients.
In my PHP script where I have my $to variable, is it simply a case of adding a comma between each recipient? or multiple $to variables?

thanks..

```
$to = "info@mysiteservices.co.uk";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, addresses must be comma delimited and comply to RFC 2822 as the manual page for this function states: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$to = "info@mysiteservices.co.uk, sales@mysiteservices.co.uk";
```